# Refactoring code: Object inside Array, data presentation

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, object, refactoring

I am working on a React-native Android/iOS App. I have an array of object look like this:

```
const shots= [
{"heatNumber": 1, "heatShotHit": 0, "heatShotNumber": 1, "hit": false, "id": "e404bd61-0a96-4e21-b6aa-36ff433f16ad", "rangeNumber": 1, "shotNumber": 1, "shotValue": 0, "stationNumber": 1, "timeFromStart": 0, "xEnd": 6, "xStart": 5, "yEnd": 5, "yStart": 6}, 

{"heatNumber": 1, "heatShotHit": 1, "heatShotNumber": 2, "hit": true, "id": "1badd0dc-59a5-4b2f-97b4-db5fdc72e13d", "rangeNumber": 1, "shotNumber": 2, "shotValue": 10, "stationNumber": 1, "timeFromStart": 163, "xEnd": 2, "xStart": 1, "yEnd": 1, "yStart": 2}, 

{"heatNumber": 1, "heatShotHit": 2, "heatShotNumber": 3, "hit": true, "id": "50a7a92c-3b26-49df-8ab8-677d6978a0a2", "rangeNumber": 1, "shotNumber": 3, "shotValue": 10, "stationNumber": 1, "timeFromStart": 268, "xEnd": 1, "xStart": 1, "yEnd": 1, "yStart": 1}, 

{"heatNumber": 1, "heatShotHit": 3, "heatShotNumber": 4, "hit": true, "id": "04b82166-1466-4b92-8c45-5ef2ecce9930", "rangeNumber": 1, "shotNumber": 4, "shotValue": 10, "stationNumber": 1, "timeFromStart": 381, "xEnd": 1, "xStart": 1, "yEnd": 1, "yStart": 1}];
```

I needed to get 3 values out of it.

1. Total hit (total number of objects).
2. Final Number of heatShotHit (finalHeatShotHit = Last object key value of heatShotHit - First object key value of heatShotHit).
3. Missed shot (Total hit - finalHeatShotHit).

I wrote the code like this,

```
    const heatCount = Object.keys(shots).length;
    const valueOfHitCalc = shots.map(a=>a.heatShotHit);
    const hit = valueOfHitCalc[valueOfHitCalc.length-1] - valueOfHitCalc[0];
    const miss = heatCount - hit;
```

Can any one suggest me with better code/refactor my code, which take lower execution time ?

Comment: You say you have an object but actually `shots` is an array of objects...

Comment: You could just do shots.length instead of using Object.keys right

Comment: Sorry, it was a mistake, I fixed it. Thank you. @Arnau.

Comment: Why not use a regular loop and do the sum and subtraction in it?

Comment: I would suggest using Array.prototype.reduce to reduce the array of objects to a single object with the computed values you need. I don't know that it's any faster but it's "cleaner" and more readable.